# Is it possible to add sub-items to a YML list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, middleman

Given the following YML format, is it possible, or advisable to map URLs so that components like nav lists can be both populated and linked?

It can be populated:

```
products:
  - Wizzy Widgets
  - Doohickeys
  - Thingamabobbers
```

renders via the following ERB (where the file is /data/product_types.yml):

```
<% data.product_types.products.each do |product_type|  %>
<li><a href="#"><%= product_type %></a></li>
<% end %>
```

to output the following markup

```
<li><a href="#">Wizzy Widgets</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Doohickeys</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Thingamabobbers</a></li>
```

but can it be linked also

```
products:
  - Wizzy Widgets:
    - url: "/wizzy-widgets"
  - Doohickeys:
    - url: "/doohickeys"
  - Thingamabobbers
    - url: "/thingamabobbers"
```

through ERB like so:

```
<% data.product_types.products.each do |product_type, product_url|  %>
<li><a href="<%= product_url %>"><%= product_type %></a></li>
<% end %>
```

so that it outputs the following markup?

```
<li><a href="/wizzy-widgets">Wizzy Widgets</a></li>
<li><a href="/doohickeys">Doohickeys</a></li>
<li><a href="/thingamabobbers">Thingamabobbers</a></li>
```

I *know* this particular example doesn't work. I'm just trying to give an example of what I'm looking to do. Is this a bad practice? If so, how would you approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in nesting YML data you can do so like this:

```
details:
  - name: "Brady Duncan"
    url: "brady-duncan"
    title: "Secretary of Beer Defense"
    bio: "Has a well rounded set of skills (the right brain) who also aggressively networks and enjoys promoting the brand."
    favorite: "Happy Amber"
  - name: "Jeff Hunt"
    url: "jeff-hunt"
    title: "Beer 'Can'nesseur"
    bio: "Has a very deep understanding of the brewing process and the science behind the 'magic'"
    favorite: "Gnarly Brown"
  - name: "Kenny McNutt"
    url: "kenny-mcnutt"
    title: "The 'Beer'ded Baron"
    bio: "The man with the financial plan who also has a refined pallet for identifying flavors in beer."
    - favorite:
      beer: "Psychopathy"
      music: "Bluegrass"
      movies: "Drama"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
require 'yaml'

yml = YAML.load(%{
  products:
    -
      name: Wizzy Widgets
      url: /wizzy-widgets
    -
      name: Doohickeys
      url: /doohickeys
    -
      name: Thingamabobbers
      url: /thingamabobbers
})

yml["products"].each do |product|
  puts %{<li><a href="#{product["url"]}%>">#{product["name"]}</a></li>}
end
```

Comment: Also note the spacing is important here. "-" must be indented by a single space (not a tab), and followed by a single space. And url & name must be indented by two spaces (not tabs either).

Comment: You can do this in a .yml file? I should mention that this is not a typical RoR app. It's using Middleman.

Comment: @KevinSuttle the Yaml part is the bit between `yml = YAML.load(%{` and  `})`. It has just been put in a Ruby string like this to demonstrate that it works. The important bit for you I think is using a `name` key in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

use a hash in yml

```
products:
  Wizzy Widgets:
    /wizzy-widgets
  Doohickeys:
    /doohickeys
  Thingamabobbers:
    /thingamabobbers
```

erb like your second example

```
<% data.product_types.products.each do |product_type, product_url|  %>
  <li><a href="<%= product_url %>"><%= product_type %></a></li>
<% end %>
```